# Raw chicken 2 hour/4 hour time

Tags: food-safety, chicken

I left raw chicken in my car for just under two hours at 11 degrees Celsius (51.8 F) by accident. Apparently this is safe (?) as it is under two hours and the temperature outside is not high. I put it straight in the freezer  and then the fridge to cool it quickly. Does this mean I have to be extra careful with this particular piece of meat as there is the four hour total window and two hours is already used up? Thanks!

Edit: The answer to this question helped me. [How many times is it safe to reheat chicken?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16421/how-many-times-is-it-safe-to-reheat-chicken/16425#16425)

Answer (score 1):

The "danger zone" is 4.4° C - 60° C, so it was in the danger zone. It should not be left there for more than a total of *2* hours - and yours was 2.

On top of that, freezing does not reset this countdown, it only stops it temporarily. You probably shouldn't eat this piece of meat, it isn't worth the risk.